# If $A$ is a open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ not bounded above. exists $x_{0}>0$ such that $A$ contains infinite point $mx_{0}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> If $A$ is a open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ not bounded above. exists $x_{0}>0$ such that $A$ contains contains infinitely many points of the form $mx_{0}$ with $m\in \mathbb{N}$.

since $A$ is not bounded above for all $M> 0$ there exists $a_{0}$ in $A$ such that $a_{0}>M$, in the same way there exists $a_{1}\in A$ such that $a_{1}> a_{0}$ and so on I can find an increasing sequence, can I affirm or find that the sequence contains elements of that form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose not. Then for each $x>0$ there is an $m_x\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $kx\notin A$ whenever $kx>m_x$. For each $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $D_m=\{x>0:m_x=m\}$.

Fix $a>0$. The interval $[0,a]$ is not the union of countably many nowhere dense sets, so there is an $m(a)\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $D_{m(a)}\cap[0,a]$ is dense in some interval $(u_a,v_a)\subseteq[0,a]$. Since $\Bbb R\setminus A$ is closed, it is not hard to show that $[u_a,v_a]\subseteq D_{m(a)}$.

Finally, there is an $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $S=\{a>0:m(a)=n\}$ is uncountable.

Now let $U=\{x\in A:x>n\}$; clearly $U$ is open and non-empty, so it contains an open interval $(y,z)$. Let $a\in S\cap(0,z-y)$ and $x\in(u_a,v_a)$. Then $x<z-y$, so there is a $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $kx\in(y,z)\subseteq A$, but on the other hand $x\in D_n$, and $kx>n$, so $kx\notin A$, and we have the desired contradiction.